# Keeping servlet stream open without blocking work thread

Tags: servlets, server-sent-events, java-ee-7

I am trying to implement HTML 5 SSE feature. For this I need to keep response stream open for long duration. Right now my implementation is as below.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {


    resp.setContentType("text/event-stream");
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();

    Broadcaster.add(pw);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000*60*60);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestServelet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    Broadcaster.remove(pw);
}
```

I the above code i am making thread to sleep for 1 hour, so that I can keep PrintWriter open for 1 hour. I know suspending thread is not good method.

I want to know is there any better why where I can keep PrintWriter open even after call to servlet is returned? Or is there any different approach to achieve this effect?

Comment: Check out Servlet 3.0 [Async Servlet features](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/async-servlet-feature-of-servlet-3.html).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Looks like this will help. Will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/html5-server-sent-events-java-servlets-example/) You will find sample application (HTML+Servlets) which will probably meet Your requirements.

You can also use [WebSockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket.htm#GKJIQ5)

Comment: Actually code mentioned in question works. I have prepared my code using same link which you have provided ( [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/html5-server-sent-events-java-servlets-example/) ). I want to improve efficiency by not using Thread.sleep().